# Vim help outputs gibberish

Tags: help-system, error

While going through the vimtutor, I was supposed to execute commands to access help. Executing `:help` worked, but once I executed `:help w`, `:help user-manual` the output became gibberish.

[image]

The error code that was provided upon executing these commands was **E434: Can't find tag pattern**.

A previously posted proposed solution of installing `vim-enhanced` yielded no results.

Comment: Note the filename: `usr_toc.txt.gz`. For some reason, you are seeing a gzipped file instead of the expected text file. You should start your investigation with the packages you have installed.

Comment: I recall having seen this once when I was on a system with only compressed help files. What happens if you run `:helptags ALL` and try again?

Comment: See `:help faq-4.6`.

Comment: See here: https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-4.6

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I did not test running `:help w` without any modifications, and instead immediately ran `:helptags ALL`, as you mentioned. This seemed to work and it no longer outputs gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-4.6) suggests one solution for working with compressed help files (using `'helpfile'` and more).

I find that sometimes fixing the tags with `:helptags ALL` works just fine (so did the OP).